# How to count records of a list with a specific property in OCaml?

Tags: list, count, ocaml, record

Lets say we have a record which defines a person type with the properties `name` and `age`:

```
type person = {name:string ; age:int };;
```

and initialize a list with different types:

```
let personlist = [{name="alexander";age=21};{name="benjamin";age=30};{name="claudia";age=21}];;
```

How can I count the amount of types with a specific age, lets say 21 (alexander and claudia) so that the output in this case would be two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most straightforward way would be to combine `List.length` and `List.filter`.

```
List.(personlist |> filter (fun p -> p.age = 21) |> length)
```

However, this is somewhat less efficient than it could be. We can do it in one pass because we don't really need to build a list of the matching people, and then iterate over that list to find its length.

`List.fold_left` will let us iterate over `personlist`, updating the initial value of `0` on each iteration dependent on whether the `age` field of each record is `21` or not.

```
List.fold_left (fun i {age; _} -> i + if age = 21 then 1 else 0) 0 personlist
```

This can be generalized as a `count` function which takes a predicate function as an argument.

```
let count p lst = 
  lst 
  |> List.fold_left (fun i x -> i + Bool.to_int (p x)) 0
```